# d3.js v4 - Not able to append text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet.markercluster

I have the following function that helps me to draw legends on a leaflet map.

```
/*Function for generating a legend with the same categories as in the clusterPie*/
function renderLegend() {
var data = d3.entries(metadata.fields[categoryField].lookup),
    legenddiv = d3.select('body').append('div')
        .attr('id','legend');
console.log(data);

var heading = legenddiv.append('div')
    .classed('legendheading', true)
    .text(metadata.fields[categoryField].name);

var legenditems = legenddiv.selectAll('.legenditem')
    .data(data);
console.log("Partial");

legenditems.enter().append('div').attr('class', function(f){return 'category-'+f.key;})
    .text(function(f){console.log('hi'); return f.value;});

legenditems.classed({'legenditem': true});
```

When I remove the `.classed({'legenditem': true})` part, I see the legends rendering momentarily but not staying there and if I keep it, it gives an error message `text is not a function`. I think it's something related to the above code being written in D3 v3. But I can't seem to figure out exactly what.

Comment: Just do `.classed('legenditem', true)`, like the previous one.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry for my dumb doubts, I am very new to d3.
By doing like previous do you mean `legenditems.enter().append('div').attr('class', function(f){return 'category-'+f.key;});



    legenditems.classed({'legenditem': true}).text(function(f){return f.value;});`? 
This gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`.

Comment: Nope. Again, just do `.classed('legenditem', true)`.

Comment: :( I am not quite getting it right. I think I have thoroughly misunderstood you. I updated the code with what I understood from your statements. But it seems to throw an error. Apologies.

Comment: Again, this is very simple: wherever you have `.classed({'legenditem': true})`, change it to `.classed('legenditem', true)`. Do you understand? It has to be `.classed('legenditem', true)`, **NOT** `.classed({'legenditem': true})`.

Comment: Oh, God. I was not seeing the difference. I feel so dumb. Thanks a lot for helping me out. 
It is not throwing an error now, but the legend is rendering and disappearing. Which is a different problem I think.